# Rails rufus-scheduler jobs returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, singleton, rufus-scheduler

I'm using rufus-scheduler to schedule jobs at a certain date through the following code:

```
  job = Rufus::Scheduler.singleton.schedule_at @post.read_attribute(:parse_time).to_s do

  end
```

I then save the id of that job in my post class

```
  @post.update_attribute(:job_id, job.id)
```

However, if I try and access that job again by calling:

```
  Rufus::Scheduler.singleton.job(@post.read_attribute(:job_id)).unschedule
```

I get an error because the job is nil. If I try and look at the jobs of the Scheduler by calling:

```
  Rufus::Scheduler.singleton.jobs
```

I get a blank array. Can anyone explain why my jobs aren't <strike>saving properly</strike> kept / being tracked?

Here's my initialization file for the scheduler. Do I have to do anything to enable singleton though? Or does it come with rails automatically:

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

# Create singleton rufus scheduler
s = Rufus::Scheduler.singleton
```

Comment: You are omitting important information. What version of Ruby? What version of rufus-scheduler? What server are you running Rails on top of? (Passenger, Webrick, Thin, Unicorn). Be specific.

Comment: I'm running Ruby v2.0.0p195, rufus-scheduler 3.0.7, with a WEBrick server. What do you mean when you say "keeps the jobs in memory?" how is that different from keeping jobs saved? Is there a recommended method for doing what I'm trying to do? Thanks for the help

Comment: I mean that rufus-scheduler doesn't save jobs to a file, a database or in a cookie jar.

Comment: I guess I didn't fully understand how to work with jobs when I finished looking at the readme. Do you have any recommendations for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: 1) accept my answer
2) maybe create a Job model and work with it ( https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/#callable-handler ) The Job model could directly be triggerable by rufus-scheduler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rufus-scheduler doesn't keep triggered jobs around.

Your job has probably triggered and is gone.

Comment: By triggered jobs do you mean jobs that have been scheduled, or jobs that have been scheduled and subsequently run by the scheduler? I'm trying to obtain a reference to jobs that have been scheduled but haven't ran yet. Thanks for the help!

Comment: By "triggered" I mean "jobs that have been scheduled and subsequently run by the scheduler". Jobs that have been scheduled but haven't ran yet should be visible (if you're in the same Ruby process as the scheduler and address the right scheduler instance).

Comment: I guess I'm addressing the wrong scheduler instance then, because the jobs haven't triggered yet but aren't found when I try and search for them by id from the Rufus::Scheduler.singleton

Comment: Another common issue, is with forking servers: new ruby process, no jobs. But with Webrick no such niceties... The singleton code is here, shouldn't play any trick: https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/blob/master/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb#L101-L106

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look into it and report back with any errors I've found!

Comment: Oh wow... It was an unrelated error in my controller that was using a past date for setting the jobs, so they instantly triggered when I scheduled them. Code is working fine now. Thank you!